# MacOS Java 6 mishandles AppleDisplayScaleFactor when set globally, and ignores it entirely when set application-specific

Tags: java, macos

Later versions of MacOS (> 10.5?) support a spiffy property, AppleDisplayScaleFactor - the scale factor for an application window, which can be set either globally, or for a specific application (identified by the CFBundleIdentifier in the app's info.plist - as I understand it).

BUT... my Java Swing application is a mess when I use this value globally - clicks don't match up with buttons, bad screen painting and so forth - and the same thing happens running JavaSoundDemo. And when I try to use it in a app-specific manner it is never used at all (I tried a variety of "identifiers" for the app - CFBundleIdentifier for the app, for the JVM, and the Main class, which is used as the title for the JVM window).

I'm just hoping that some brave and clever soul has figured out how to make this actually work - the Apple docs on "Resolution-Independent Display" claim that Java simply does everything for you. Perhaps this really should be a bug report to Apple - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `AppleDisplayScaleFactor` doesn't work across all applications (such as Flash within a browser). So it doesn't surprise me that it doesn't work properly with Java Swing.